# Why isn't $\log_1 (1) = 1$?

Tags: logarithms

- Exponential form: $a^b = c$.
- Logarithmic form: $\log_a(c) = b$.

$1^1 = 1$; therefore, $\log_1(1) = 1$, but it isn't.

Furthermore, isn't the result of $\log_x(x)$ always 1?

Why is there an error? What am I actually doing in $\log_1(1)$?

Comment: One to the power anything equals one.

Comment: $\log_1(x)$ is not defined

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\log_1(1)$ could be any number, because any number solves the equation $1^x = 1$. This is a bad thing for a function (which is what we want the logarithm to be), so we leave it undefined.

This is entirely analoguous to $\frac00$ being left undefined, because any number solves $0x = 0$.

Even more analoguously, $\frac a0$ for $a \neq 0$ is being left undefined for the same reason that $\log_1(b)$ for $b \neq 1$ is, although it's a different twain from the one above. This time it's because the corresponding equations $0x = a$ and $1^x = b$ have *no* solutions.

As to your furthermore, it is rather the case that $\log_\color{red}x(\color{blue}x) = 1$ (as long as $x>0, x\neq 1$). This is because $\color{red}x^1 = \color{blue}x$, and $1$ is the only number that fits in there and still makes it an equality.